# Determine when a new customer registers from within custom module (Magento)

Tags: php, magento, module

I am working on a module that will allow the customer to not only sign up with our webstore, but also give them the ability to register with another site via a web service. How do I determine, from within my module, when a customer is registering so that I can send the appropriate information off to the other site?

Comment: Here is my answer for similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472137/magento-new-user-registration-inject-own-code/7489243#7489243

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a good event system that dispatches events to registered observers when they occur. This allows you to do exactly what you want.

Take a look at customer_register_success event ( app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php : 322 )

More on event/observer pattern in magento:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Answer (score 0):

<s>actually there is no event for user registring</s> Ok, there is one (see [code_burgar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770005/determine-when-a-new-customer-registers-from-within-custom-module-magento/7770190#7770190)), but it ain't fired when customer register during checkout. So your best shot is the customer_save_before and check if there is an id (if there is not, it means he's new)

Comment: @code_burgar this is true, but won't work if customer register during checkout. I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: I consider that broken in that case :)